# Prove by mathematical induction that $n^\frac{1}{n}<2-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: inequality, induction

Could I have some guidance on how to conduct the inductive step in this proof (i.e. how to apply the assumption that P(k) holds true to prove P(k+1) )...
$$n^\frac{1}{n}<2-\frac{1}{n}, \ n≥2$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. I've tried taking the log of both sides but I wasn't able to proceed further; I've also attempted proving that (n^1/n+1 + 1/n+1)<n^1/n + 1/n) but was also unable to proceed further to the conclusion

Comment: @Dfernando FYI, details like what is in your comment above which are important for the question (e.g., to help avoid people down-voting and/or voting to close because they think you haven't put any effort into it) should be edited into the question text itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $n \geq 3$, show that $ (n+1) ^ \frac{ 1}{ n+1} < n^ \frac{1}{n} < 2 - \frac{1}{n} < 2 - \frac{ 1}{ n+1}$.

So start with base case of $n=3$.

Deal with the case $n = 2 $ separately.